# var is undefined if using var keyword node

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Building a small MVC. When I'm receiving results back from my model, the variable that I'm using to send to my view is undefined if I use the "var" keyword. If I don't use the keyword the object comes through just fine. What is happening?

Controller

```
const homeModel = require('../models/homeModel.js');

exports.index = function(req, res){

homeModel.getAllStores(function (err, res) {
    if (err) return err;
    stores = res; // Works
    var stores = res // Undefined
})

console.log(stores);
res.render('home', {stores: stores});
}
```

Here is the Model

```
const db = require('../db.js');

exports.getAllStores = function(done) {

db.query('select * from stores;', (err, rows) => {
    if (err) return done(err);

    let resultJson = JSON.stringify(rows);
    resultJson = JSON.parse(resultJson);

    return done(null, resultJson);

})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the declaration of `stores` to the function enclosing `homeModel.getAllStores()`. This is because JavaScript is [function (lexically) scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), so a variable will be scoped to the nearest enclosing function. You can read more about how variables that are declared using `var` work on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

In Node.js, if you don't provide the `var` keyword before your variable then it is globally scoped to the module in which it is running, this is why `console.log(stores)` works when you use `stores = res` and not `var stores = res`.

To properly scope your variable using `var`, just move your declaration to the function being exported.

Additionally, your `console.log()` and `res.render()` calls are occurring before the callback function for `homeModel.getAllStores()` is executed and setting `stores = res`. Since `res.render()` and `console.log()` will only work as expected within the callback to `homeModel.getAllStores()` you can simplify `index()` and the callback to `homeModel.getAllStores()`.

```
const homeModel = require('../models/homeModel.js')

exports.index = (req, res) => {
  return homeModel.getAllStores((err, stores) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }

    console.log(stores)
    return res.render('home', {stores})
  })
}
```

You could also use `util.promisify()` and `async/await` to write this a little more straightforward.

```
const {promisify} = require('util')
const getAllStores = promisify(require('../models/homeModel').getAllStores)

const index = async (req, res) => {
  let stores
  try {
    stores = await getAllStores()
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return res.sendStatus(500)
  }

  return res.render('home', {stores})
}

module.exports = {index}
```

Here is an example with `Promise.all()` waiting for the results from multiple queries with a hypothetical `UserModel` with `getAllUsers()` that works identically to `homeModel.getAllStores()` but queries a `users` table.

```
const {promisify} = require('util')
const getAllUsers = promisify(require('../models/userModel').getAllUsers)
const getAllStores = promisify(require('../models/homeModel').getAllStores)

const index = async (req, res) => {
  let queryResults
  try {
    queryResults = await Promise.all([getAllStores, getAllUsers])
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return res.sendStatus(500)
  }

  let [stores, users] = queryResults

  return res.render('home', {stores, users})
}

module.exports = {index}
```

Comment: I should have added that even when i set it like that, It's still undefined.

Comment: Sorry, my bad I was in a rush answering your question at first and made a mistake, you also needed to move your `console.log()` and your `res.render()` into your callback as they were getting executed before your callback was setting `stores = res`

Comment: Thanks! Would that then defeat the idea of being able to pass different SQL results into my res.render()? For example, Im going to have a Users query to pass into the same view.

Comment: Nope, its still going to render whatever the contents of the `stores` variable is assigned. So if it was a totally different select being performed within `homeModel.getAllStores()`, your `res.render()` doesn't care whats actually within the variable.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understand you. If I had another query that returned all my users, should i call res.render() once? eg res.render('home', {stores, users}). I would expect that I need to move res.render out of the functions that retrieve SQL info. So that I would be able to a couple difference functions parsing/ retrieving data, to make it look pretty, and then pass all those variables into the view.

Comment: If you need to perform multiple queries within the same route then you'll need some type of async control flow like `Promise.all()` to run each query, get the results and then pass them to `res.render()`. In that case you'd need to do call `res.render()` in after all queries finished. `Promise.all(queries).then(models =>{ res.render('home', {models} })`. In this snippet, it runs a set of Promise returning query functions and then passes the array results from the queries to `res.render()` as `models`. This however, isn't that useful and you'd probably need to transform the `models` array.

Comment: @Jeff I updated my answer to show how multiple queries could be achieved, hope that helps to better illustrate my previous comment.

Comment: I see exactly what your trying to do but In this case, stores and users are returning functions. Unless thats because my model should not be returning the done(). I was trying to move this over to chat instead of creating a long comment section, but i don't have enough points.